# How to start R without packages loaded

Tags: r, rstudio

when I start R (RStudio) I am always starting with these packages:

```
dput(loadedNamespaces())

c("zoo", "tidyselect", "xfun", "shinyjs", "purrr", "corrplot", 
"urca", "lattice", "vars", "colorspace", "vctrs", "generics", 
"htmltools", "yaml", "grDevices", "utf8", "rlang", "pillar", 
"glue", "DBI", "forecast", "TTR", "lifecycle", "quantmod", "timeDate", 
"munsell", "gtable", "evaluate", "knitr", "tseries", "strucchange", 
"lmtest", "parallel", "curl", "fansi", "methods", "xts", "Rcpp", 
"scales", "fracdiff", "ggplot2", "stats", "datasets", "graphics", 
"digest", "stringi", "dplyr", "grid", "quadprog", "tools", "sandwich", 
"magrittr", "tibble", "crayon", "pkgconfig", "ellipsis", "MASS", 
"rsconnect", "utils", "assertthat", "rmarkdown", "base", "R6", 
"nnet", "nlme", "compiler")
```

I have searched for .Rprofile, but it returns FALSE same for .RData.

```
(my_rprofile <- file.path(Sys.getenv("R_USER"), ".RProfile"))
file.exists(my_rprofile)
file.exists(".RProfile")
```

Reinstallation of R also did not help. I would love to start R only with basic packages.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If so, please edit the tags.

Comment: I suspect you are loading a saved workspace. Go to the *Global Options*  in RStudio and remove the relevant check mark.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have unchecked "Restore .RData into workspace at startup", however it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like you have an .Rprofile somewhere that is loading some packages on startup.

You could try starting [without loading any profiles](https://rstats.wtf/r-startup.html#disabling-startup-files)? In Rstudio, you can do this by just checking the option `Project Options -> Disable .Rprofile execution on session start / resume`. See screenshot:

[image: Rstudio Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the thing is that I am not using any project, I just use scrips only and It appears that I cannot open the pictured tab.

Comment: What happens if you do create a project and then check that option?

Comment: Well, basically nothing changed still packages loaded. I searched for .Rprofile and .RData deleted all... however still the same problem.

Comment: I would love to load only basic packages at the start...